# Сгенерировать пары из массива

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
Есть массив:

```
array(1,7,9,10);
```

Как мне получить из него пары, но не просто разбив случайно по 2 числа, а чтобы каждое было в паре с каждым и несколько раз. 
Например, из этого массива мне нужно получить значения:

```
array(1,7);
array(1,9);
array(1,10);
array(7,9);
array(7,10);
array(9,10);
```

То-есть все числа встречаются в парах, так-же бывает, что нужно сгенерировать эти пары несколько раз, причем так, чтобы они менялись местами. 
Например если нужно это сделать 3 раза - получится что числа 1 и 7 встретятся 3 раза так в паре:

```
array(1,7);
array(7,1);
array(1,7);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал проще и универсальнее. Пусть это будет одна функция, которая принимает исходные данные и количество повторений.

**Код:**

```
<?php

function generateArrayPairs(array $data, int $repeat = 1) {
    $data = array_values($data); // Чтобы убедиться, что индексы идут по порядку
    $result = []; // Контейнер с результатом

    foreach ($data as $outerKey => $outerElement) {
        $internalData = array_slice($data, $outerKey + 1); // для формирования пары оставляем только элементы справа от текущего 
        foreach ($internalData as $innerKey => $innerElement) {
            $pair = [$outerElement, $innerElement]; // Сохраняем, т.к. в случае повторения пара нам ещё понадобится
            $result[] = $pair; // Добавляем пару в результат

            if ($repeat > 1) {
                $reversedPair = [$innerElement, $outerElement]; // Тоже сохраняем, чтобы не генерировать кучу раз.

                for ($i = 2; $i <= $repeat; $i++) {
                    $result[] = ($i % 2 == 0) ? $reversedPair : $pair; // меняем элементы местами каждое 2-е повторение
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Поиграться и посмотреть результат можно здесь: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b487ef1efb283df6244349fcad0ef3af2a4ed51

Comment: Вот спасибо!)
Вчера всю голову сломал)))

Answer (score 1):

Это только по уникальным парам, правила повторения не указаны.

```
$data = array(1,8,9,10);
$final = array();
for($index = 0; $index < count($data); $index++) {
    for ($subIndex = $index; $subIndex < count($data); $subIndex++) {
        $first = $data[$index];
        $second = $data[$subIndex];
        if($index != $subIndex && (!isset($data[$index . '-' . $subIndex]) || !isset($data[$subIndex . '-' . $index]))) {
            $final[$index . '-' . $subIndex] = array($data[$index], $data[$subIndex]);
        }
    }
}
$final = array_values($final);
```